# InnoSetup-installed Eclipse RCP application ignores -data argument

Tags: configuration, eclipse-rcp, inno-setup

I built a Eclipse RCP application and packaged it using InnoSetup. When I install the packaged application to the default destination (C:\Program Files\XXX), the -data argument in the INI-file gets ignored (it is set to the installation directory: -data C:\Program Files\XXX). Instead, the configuration data is saved in the user's application data folder. If I install it to C:\XXX, the -data argument works as advertised and the configuration data is saved in the installation folder.

If I copy a non-packaged build of my application in a folder under C:\Program Files, interestingly, the -data argument is also regarded correctly, unlike the packaged installation.

The InnoSetup script file has no direct instructions to set a directory for configuration data, so I think it is an issue with Eclipse RCP. Furthermore, the write permission for all the folders talked about here are complete for all users.

I'd be glad for pointers where to look, in order to force Eclipse RCP to save my configuration data where I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

By default, unelevated users are not permitted to write files to Program Files or any subfolders thereof.  While it is possible to change the folder permissions to permit this, it is strongly discouraged as (a) this doesn't permit settings to be recorded per-user, which is typically a requirement even if at first you don't think it is, and (b) permitting global write access on a folder containing executable files is a security exploit waiting to happen.  It's less critical if you do so on a subfolder containing only data files. but this still presents a privacy and data-security hole as now any user on the system (or network users) can look at and modify the main user's data.

Vista and Win7 will automatically redirect access to read-only Program Files subfolders to the VirtualStore folder in the user's AppData area if the application is not marked with a Vista compatibility manifest that includes the required permissions (which should almost without exception be "asInvoker").